# Gmail forward all email - respond as original receiver

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

I have two Gmail addresses/accounts, `OfficialAddressA` and `PrivateAdressB`. I have set all incoming emails to `OfficialAddressA` to be forwarded to `PrivateAdressB`, and remove Gmail's copy. Now I want to answer a forwarded email in my private account, as if I was answering from the official account, so that the "From:" still says `OfficialAddressA`.

Is it possible to accomplish this?

I think I have done before from another address but I can't remember how I did it.

Comment: Have you tried setting up a "Send Mail As" address in Setting? (Can you do this with another Gmail address?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to Settings - Accounts and Import - Send mail as.
Select "Reply from the same address the message was sent to"

You still can change the address you want to reply with before sending the email.

I tried this myself and works fine.